# Is the this function executed twice?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the code below:

```
select t.id, ST_AsText(t.geom) AS tgeom, s.name, ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(t.geom,s.geom)) AS short,t.par
from teta t, str_lines s
Where ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(t.geom,s.geom))<200
```

Is  ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(t.geom,s.geom)) executed twice ?

Answer (score 1):

good question.  but if instead you use 'WHERE short < 200' then it won't need to calculate it twice.

Comment: According to this super old interenets, you can't do that:

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/18195.1038530280@sss.pgh.pa.us

> Evaluation of the WHERE clause logically precedes evaluation of the
> SELECT list, so it's really quite nonsensical to expect SELECT outputs
> to be available in WHERE.

but that sounds really crazy that you can't use an aliased column in the select in the where clause

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is executed twice.

Once in your where clause
and once in your column aliasing code.

> That sucks..so i guess it would be better performance-wise to make my
>   own function and cache ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(t.geom,s.geom)), huh?

Consider the following:

create table st_length_temp
as select ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(t.geom,s.geom)) as length
from dual;  --or whatever your equivalent of Oracle's dual is.

Now your query becomes:

```
select t.id, ST_AsText(t.geom) AS tgeom, s.name,l.length AS short,t.par
from teta t, str_lines s, st_length_temp l
Where l.length < 200
```

Comment: That sucks..so i guess it would be better performance-wise to make my own function and cache ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(t.geom,s.geom)), huh?

Comment: @osh Updated my answer for you

Answer (score 0):

You could try packing it into a subquery, but I fear the optimiser will first create the cartesian product {teta * str_lines} before applying the join condition.

```
SELECT id, tgeom, name, short, par
FROM( select t.id
    , ST_AsText(t.geom) AS tgeom
    , s.name
    , ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(t.geom,s.geom)) AS short
    , t.par
    from teta t, str_lines s
    ) pair
Where pair.short < 200
```

BTW: what does the `JOIN` syntax version do ?:

```
select t.id
  , ST_AsText(t.geom) AS tgeom
  , s.name
  , ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(t.geom,s.geom)) AS short
  ,t.par
from teta t
JOIN str_lines s ON ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(t.geom,s.geom))<200
   ;
```